# c++ accessing integers individually

Tags: c++, integer

I'm writing a simple encryption program for my studies and I'm stuck on something so simple. I have input a 3 digit number into a variable called Number. I am now trying to put each of the three digits into separate variables called n1, n2 and n3 so i can manipulate them individually.

I thought I could just do number[1] etc but I keep getting errors.

Any idea how to do this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for the number `345`. The idea is to divide and then read the last digit with `% 10`.

```
int number = 345;

int n1 = number / 100;
int n2 = (number / 10) % 10;
int n3 = number % 10;
```

What you have tried could work if `number` was a string.